# IIS Express Azure Web Role URL Stuck on 127.255.0.0:82

Tags: debugging, azure, iis-express, azure-web-roles

I have a webrole + azure cloud solution that was working great, and then all of a sudden i hit debug while having another solution open and running and the solution threw a 500 error.

Now when i hit debug to try to debug locally, my browser points me at 127.0.0.1:82 and i get a 500.

When i look at the IIS Express tray, it says the site is up at 127.255.0.0:82-- though i see nothing there.

How do i get my site to run on 127.0.0.1:81 again? I just want it to work like it used to and like my other sites do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to restart my computer, and then go into settings for my WebRole in the Azure/Cloud project, go to the endpoints config screen and edit the endpoint and then change it back. After that, my site ran on 127.0.0.1 again.